# Please help me understand what's wrong with my python question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[My question - Linux, how to simulate environment is which python is not installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459248/linux-how-to-simulate-environment-is-which-python-is-not-installed) has got 6 downvotes without any explanation

If you google my question title, you will not find many "relevant" links. So I wonder why people are downvoting it.

Edit. I have deleted the question to avoid getting more downvotes - You can see the archived question [here](http://archive.is/ETiHm)

Comment: it doesn't make any sense to me as to why you have deleted the question and put a link to an image of it in? this doesn't help anyone as people in the future who might have the same problem would not find this post, and if the link breaks, the information is gone

Comment: @WhatsThePoint General rule: "if it's downvoted it's probably not useful". / For the purpose of meta discussion that can be helpful.

Comment: (remark: Obviously wanting to make one's question better is **good**. So, +1.)

Comment: @user202729 by OP leaving a picture to the question because they want to keep the information means they think the information is good enough for other people, so the correct action would've been to leave the question active, and similar to what they have done here is ask for improvements and edit the question to make it better for other people

Comment: @WhatsThePoint It's common for meta posts to have an image of posts, even if they are deleted. | I don't think that there is any way to "ask for improvement" other than making a meta question like this.

Comment: @user202729 but its not common to create the meta post, deleting the original question and leaving an image in the meta post of the original question to help future readers of the original problem

Comment: @WhatsThePoint OP never said why they put the image there.

Comment: @user202729 quoted from OPs comment on the answer "I'm sorry for future readers who have similar question - I had to delete the question - otherwise there were many useful comments"

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: OP was forced to delete his question due to the meta effect, when the meta question was posted the SO post had only two downvotes, when deleted an hour later, it had six.

Comment: @user202729 i deleted as i was getting too many downvotes.

Answer (score -3):

It is a bit ironic that your meta question was also downvoted without explanation :P

On a more serious note, in my view your question was reasonable, but it included the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag, which is known to be pretty strict, compared to other unix tools.

The main issue is probably that people felt it wasn't directly programming related, but more of environment setup. This is explicitly on-topic per the help center, but some people dislike these questions and shut them down.

Going forward, I would expect that question to be better received at [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) SE site. It is definitely on topic there, and there are knowledgeable people there that might help with the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have been on SO for some years now, this was the first time I was confused about downvotes on my question! I'm sorry for future readers who have similar question - I had to delete the question - otherwise there were many useful comments (see archived question in OP)